# How to to access ObjectContext objects while updating entities generated by ADO.NET

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

first I am very new to ADO.NET, LINQ and those data access technologies. As far as I understand for what I readed and found on internet LINQ2SQL evolved to LINQ to entities which evolved to ADO.NET. Maybe I am wrong with those concepts so let me know.

Now to the question. I am developing a system in VS2010 (.NET 4.0) with ADO.NET to manage a school. The solution is dividedn in 3 layers: Presentation Layer (only GUI), Bussiness Layer (all process are done here) and Data Layer (only querys and database access).

The database has a table People to store data for persons (students, teachers, administrative, etc.) with a field for Nationality which stores a reference to the Countries table with all the existing countries by now.

In my first approach, I created a singleton class called ConnectionManager which stores the connection string and a reference to the database model (The code generated by the ADO.NET  Entity Data Model designer), an object which inherits from ObjectContext called SystemEntities.

At this point everything woked fine, however I wondered about the following scenario: A user is editing a person information when a lient arrives and request an bill for her payment; then the user switches to a bill form, fills the data and saves before print. During this process a call to SystemEntities.SaveChanges is made so all changes are saved to the database, then the unfinished changes made to the editeded person are saved, but this is an undesired behavior.

Then I readed that I must not have a singleton which keeps the connection to the database open. Every ObjectContext mus be disposed after fetching the data, therefore a code like this shoud be used.

To fetch all people

```cs
public static T[] QueryAll<T>() where T : Person
{
    using (SystemEntities context = ConnectionManager.Instance.GetContext())
    {
        return context.People
            .OfType<T>()
            .Include("Emails")
            .Include("Phones")
            .OrderBy(affiliate => affiliate.LastName + " " + affiliate.FirstName)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

To fetch a country

```cs
public static Country GetByID(string id)
{
    using (SystemEntities context = ConnectionManager.Instance.GetContext())
    {
        return context.Countries.FirstOrDefault(country => country.CountryID == id);
    }
}
```

Now, when I tried to edit a Person, to be specific to change a person's country, an exception is rised:

```
The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined
because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
```

This is done via the following code:

```cs
public Person Person
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        this.person = value;
        ...
        this.cmbNationality.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", person, "Nationality");
        this.cmdAddressCountry.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", person, "Country");
        ...
    }
}

private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Country[] countries = Country.QueryAll();
    Country mexico = Country.GetByA2("MX");
    this.cmbNationality.DataSource = countries;
    this.cmdAddressCountry.DataSource = countries;
    this.cmbNationality.SelectedItem = mexico;
    this.cmdAddressCountry.SelectedItem = mexico;
}
```

So when you change the item in the cmbNationality and cmdAddressCountry combo boxes, the exception is thrown. Notice that is only a change, no save has been performed.

As far as I understand, this is produced because the Person and Country objects are fetched from the database from different SystemEntities (ObjectContext) objects.

And there is the problem and question. How can I solve that if I can not use a singleton and all contexts must be disposed after use? Of course I can create several methods to avoid this problem to make updates by hand or not using data bindings but, what is the point of ADO.NET if you must do updates at hand?

Maybe is a stupid or trivial (or may be i just didn't know how to search the answer) question but I was not able to find the answer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

why not set golbal object "SystemEntities context" in class and when in Constructor use\

`"context = ConnectionManager.Instance.GetContext()"`,so you will get the same

```
SystemEntities (ObjectContext) objects.
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: OP already had a singleton context and is trying to move away from that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're using a standard disconnected model. Since you're disconnected, yoou must re-hydrate your entity from the current context whenever persisting the modified object. The following hopefully better illustrates what I'm saying:

```
    public static Person PersistPerson(Person person)
    {
        using (SystemEntities context = ConnectionManager.Instance.GetContext())
        {
            bool doInsert = false;
            var p = context.People.Where(d => d.PersonId == person.PersonId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (p == null)
            {
                p = new Person();
                doInsert = true;
            }

            //update connected Entity
            p.LastName = person.LastName;
            p.Emails = person.Emails;
            //etc...
            if(doInsert)                    
                context.People.AddObject(person);

            context.SaveChanges();
            person.PersonId = p.PersonId;
        }
        return person;
    }
```

Comment: Indeed I tried that approach and also with SP. The problem is not when saving to the database, even was not able to reach that point. The problem is when you have a person p and you do: 'p.Nationality = (Country)comboBox.SelectedItem;' since comboBox was filled via data bounding with an array of Country objects which comes from a context different from peron's context, the error is rised during the assignment.

Comment: Well, this may not appear as elegant, but I assume that the actual Person table has something like NationalityId, in which case you could just set that Id property on your Person entity (e.g. p.NationalityId = Country.CountryId).  This presumes that you are not also adding a new Country to the database at the same time (in other words CountryId will always have a value if Country is not null).

Comment: Yes, in the database there is a Nationality field (a CountryID which references a country in the Countries table) with its respective FK. However ADO.NET does not add the Nationality as an ID, but a country object so if you want to change nationality you change the Country object (with its correspondent unique CountryID) referenced and it is suposed for ADO.NET to update those values on the database. It works well when you use a single context for the entire project and never closes it, but when you open and close conections (creating and disposing context) then exceptions are risen.